# Deleting a file without using File.Delete

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm writing a PCL for an application. As the PCL gives a basic subset of a number of standard .NET assemblies, some bits are missing - most notably, the File.* methods aren't there.

While I can replicate a lot of the required functionality without them, I don't seem to be able to delete a file. It can be done, but I cannot see how.

Any advice here would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you import `System.IO.File` ?

Comment: For a PCL, it's not available - System.IO contains the raw stream code

Comment: ah, ok. I will start to find something. Give me a sec.

Comment: I found this link https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/ . If it is your answer, let me know. Thanks. I am having some difficulty as well.

Comment: That should work - now to see if it works with mono and more over, a Xam.iOS/Xam.Android PCL